# Trimming a string from Excel

Tags: c#, .net, string, excel

I get a string from Excel as so: `"\"11/01/2011 16:00\""`

What's the most efficient way to trim this in C# so it can be parsed as a DateTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just trim the string, not sure how consistent that format will be though

```
var trimmedString = excelString.Trim('\\', '"');
```

That's assuming the string contains the slashes and those speech marks. If it's just the speech marks (because visual studio has escaped the string when displaying it) then all you need is

```
var trimmedString = excelString.Trim('"');
```

Comment: Full disclaimer, I actually prefer JS's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to trim it at all - you can just call `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` which contains the quotes at each end:

```
string text = ...;
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "'\"'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'\"'",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I don't know whether that's more efficient than trimming (there's more parsing, but no extra string to create) but I would use it for its precision: if ever the data form changes (e.g. there's no longer a quote) you'll find out because you're stating your expectations, effectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "\"11/01/2011 16:00\"";
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(myString.Substring(1, myString.Length - 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Always in that format? Can't you just substring the first 3 and last 3 characters and then Parse to a Date with a specific (supplied) date format?

Comment: Might be without the timestamp sometimes.

Comment: in which case, ken2k's solution should always work (I think). I was about to suggest DateTime.ParseExact to avoid culture problems, but I won't now! Or you might have to check the length for timestamps first.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = s.Substring(1, s.Length-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [parseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method.

```
char[] trimChars = {'\"'};
string dateTime = "\"11/01/2011 16:00\"".Trim(trimChars);

DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```